# How to make T parameter available

Tags: c#, begininvoke

I am writing an asynchronous class to simplify function operation. Below is my code:

```
using System;

namespace AsyncLibery
{
public class AsyncLibery
{
    delegate void Exec(); // No input parameter, no return value
    delegate void ExecWithParams<T>(T T1); //One input parameter, no return value
    delegate void ExecWithParams<T1, T2>(T1 t1,T2 t2); //Two input parameters, no return value 
    delegate void ExecWithParams<T1, T2, T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3);//Three input parameters, no return value
    delegate void ExecWithParams<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4);//Four input parameters,no return value

    delegate T  ExecWithReturnType<T>(); //No input parameter, one return value
    delegate T2 ExecWithReturnType<T1, T2>(T1 t1); //One input parameter, one return value
    delegate T3 ExecWithReturnType<T1, T2, T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2);//Two input parameters, one return value
    delegate T4 ExecWithReturnType<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3);//Three input parameters, one return value
    delegate T5 ExecWithReturnType<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4);// Four input parameters, one return value.

    #region no input parameter, no return value
    public void BeginInvokeEx(Action actionFunction)
    {
        Exec exec = new Exec(actionFunction);
        exec.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(EndInvokeEx), exec);
    }

    private void EndInvokeEx(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Exec exec = (Exec)iar.AsyncState;
        exec.EndInvoke(iar);
    }
    #endregion

    #region one input parameter, no return value
    public void BeginInvokeEx<T>(Action<T> actionFunction,T T1)
    {
        ExecWithParams<T> exec = new ExecWithParams<T>(actionFunction);
        exec.BeginInvoke(T1, new AsyncCallback(EndInvokeEx1), exec);
    }

    private void EndInvokeEx1(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        ExecWithParams<T> exec = (ExecWithParams<T>)iar.AsyncState;
        exec.EndInvoke(iar);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

When I complied the code, it throws me an exception like "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)", the exception is appeared at below code :

```
ExecWithParams<T> exec = (ExecWithParams<T>)iar.AsyncState;
```

I know that we must refer T parameter the specific type like int or string or anything else.
But who can help me without modifying the T parameter? is there any good method to deal with it?
thx.

Comment: Whatever you do, please please **please** rename it to `AsyncLibrary`

Comment: You're missing a `<T>` in `EndInvokeEx1`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `Func` and `Action` delegates? Or, more precisely, casting from `Action` to a custom delegate?

Comment: @Groo if I use Func, I should use it like below:     private void BeginInvokeFunction(int id) { Func<int, bool> fun = new Func<int, bool>(ExecFunction); fun.BeginInvoke(id, new AsyncCallback(EndInvokeFunction), fun); } private void EndInvokeFunction(IAsyncResult iar) { Func<int, bool> func = (Func<int, bool>)iar.AsyncState; MessageBox.Show(func.EndInvoke(iar).ToString()); } I think it's not very succinct

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - so simple advice, so true.

Comment: @OferZelig We have one or two typo-spelling mistakes in our code-base from years gone by, I have to physically restrain myself from refactoring them out... :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth  I will take care of it, thx for your advice

Comment: @Groo  if you use Func or Action, how will you write the code? do you need to declase the begininvoke function and endinvoke function?  thx :)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth don't hesitate to do that, unless you know that there are "magic strings" of these types (reflection, DI etc.). It's so annoying to see this over and over when reading the code.

Comment: @OferZelig I don't usually, but as you say "magic" strings via reflection, magic code via dynamic, and external references. We have control over them all, but it is hard to pin them all down and it incurs testing impact for zero business gain :-( I'll wait for the next unguarded check-in just before I go on holiday lol - of course I jest...

Comment: @user1118566: I am not sure what you mean. Succinct, as in "compact"? But "ExecWithParams" is a longer name than "Action", "ExecWithReturnType" is even longer. Not to mention that any .NET developer immediately knows their signatures and they are used all over BCL (LINQ uses them exclusively). I don't see any reason to use this class. If you remove the cast, you end up with a single line (call to `BeginInvoke`), and then I see no reason to create a separate class just to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `EndInvokeEx1` generic:

```
private void EndInvokeEx1<T>(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    ExecWithParams<T> exec = (ExecWithParams<T>)iar.AsyncState;
    exec.EndInvoke(iar);
}
```

And change your `BeginInvokeEx` accordingly:

```
public void BeginInvokeEx<T>(Action<T> actionFunction,T T1)
{
    ExecWithParams<T> exec = new ExecWithParams<T>(actionFunction);
    exec.BeginInvoke(T1, new AsyncCallback(EndInvokeEx1<T>), exec);
}
```

Comment: another question, how to use Func or Action to perform the asynchronouse operation by using BeginInvoke?

Comment: @user1118566: simply call `actionFunction.BeginInvoke(...)`. There is no need to create a new delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what `T` is. You need to either have a generic parameter on the method `EndInvokeEx1` such that it becomes `EndInvokeEx<T>`, where you can then pass `T` to the cast. Otherwise, it will need to be defined in the class declaration, so your class declaration becomes `public class AsyncLibrary<T>`. Otherwise, the compiler won't know what `T` is meant to represent.